# How do I add another property to an existing json object in a typescript file using typscript compiler?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-compiler-api

I have the following file with me

```
const ServerURL = '';
export const URLConfig = {
    ServerURL: ServerURL,
    entityKeyUrl: ServerURL + '/path/to/resource/',
}
```

Now I want to add another url to this object using ast/typescript compiler apis.

**What have I tried ?**

I have read the source file and extracted the text from the SourceFile but now I don't know how to update it with the new text.

Here is my code (hiding the other parts of the code)

```
const source = getSourceFile(tree, '/path/to/serverurl.constants.ts');
const txt = source.getText();
const closingBrace = txt.lastIndexOf('};');
const aLineAboveClosingBrace = closingBrace - 2;
source.update("Hello", ts.createTextChangeRange(ts.createTextSpan(0, txt.length), "Hello".length + txt.length));
```

It results in an error "Debug failed, false expression". Can somebody guide me in this ?

**Update 1**
I have been able to do some string manipulation and been able to generate my text but now to be able to create a file, I used `ts.createSourceFile` but that did not generate any file for me.

Comment: Should I just use the getText() and do some pattern matching add my stuff to it and create a new file from it ?

Comment: Where you'd like to apply this change? Should it be compilation phase or something else?

Comment: During compilation. I am doing this as part of code generation tool.

Comment: So you want to write something like custom transformer using Transformation API, right? I think that it's the best you can use here to modify your code. Do you want to modify only specific files in your project? What's the conditions to modify some object?

Comment: I think I answered your question wrongly in the comments above. I am just generating new files and adding some data in existing files. What I am having trouble with is when creating a source file using ts.createSourceFile method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it in compilation time, I'd suggest you use Transformation API to do that.

Currently TypeScript doesn't support to use custom transformers by using `tsc`, but you can use tools like [ttypescript](https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript). [See here](https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript#transformers) to see what's the custom transformer should be like. Also, in the repo's readme you can find examples of other custom transformers (you can use one of them as your start point).

Another helpful tool you can use is [ts-ast-viewer](https://ts-ast-viewer.com) - it helps you see what the AST is and how to create the same (and then modify it) AST for the code.

Comment: Can you tell me why createSourceFile did not create the file ?

Comment: I can't tell you for sure, but I guess that's because you need to emit that file after creating. It might just create an AST for source file, but nothing else.

Comment: Is there any other method that takes in ast and spits out a file ?

Comment: What's your target? You want to modify existing TypeScript file/create another TypeScript file and modify output of the compilation?

Comment: I have solved this issue by using another way to create a file and append some text to it using some string manipulation.

Comment: ES2015 is the version. I want to add another statement to my existing typescript file.

Comment: Try https://github.com/WolkSoftware/tsmod (see also https://dev.to/wolksoftware/automated-refactoring-for-typescript-apps-with-tsmod-4kko, https://ts-morph.com/manipulation/)